# ndisprot on Windows 7 64 bit without using a signed driver

Tags: windows, driver, ndis, raw-ethernet

I heard it might be possible to run ndisprot 6 on Windows 7 64 bit for development before having to create a signed driver.  Can someone help with this?  Creating a signed driver is not what I want.

I have been using ndisprot sample driver under Windows 32 bit without an issue.  How do I configure Windows so I can develop/run the unmodified sample driver.  If there is a signed sample driver I'd appreciate that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hit F8 during boot and select the "Disable Driver Signature Enforcement" option to allow loading unsigned drivers during development.